# Not getting whole flattened javascript object structure

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion

I have a nested object that I wish to retrieve certain key/value pairs from. For these to be retrieved they **must** have a value for each key.

I'm close, but I'm not getting any of the nested objects' key/value pairs.

I have created [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/slinco/ojf450ok/#&togetherjs=JAkLAUhD9b)

Here's the function I have at present:

```
function getKeysVals(obj, keys, recurse = false)
{
  let addToOutput = true;
  let out         = [];
  let cnt         = 0;
  obj.map
  (
    (thisObj) =>
    {
      let newObj = {};  // Temp holder for new object that gets added to output.

      // Loop through the requested keys, adding them to the new object:
      for( i in keys)
      {
        // Check that this key has a value:
        if(!thisObj[keys[i]])
        {
          addToOutput = false;
          break;
        }
        else
        {
          newObj[keys[i]] = thisObj[keys[i]];
        }
      }

      // Ensure we have values for ALL the requested keys in this object:
      if( addToOutput ) out.push(newObj);

      // Go round again if this object has the specified recurse object:
      if( thisObj[recurse] )
      {
        getKeysVals(thisObj[recurse], keys, recurse)
      }
    }
  );
  return out
}
```

When I call it with `result = getKeysVals(nodes[0].nodes, ['id', 'text', 'filePath'], 'nodes');` I expect to get a new array with:

```
[
    { id: 1526297185466,​​​​​ text: 'test part a',​​​​​ filePath: 'test part a-1526297185451.CSV' },
    { id: 1526297202132,​​​​​ text: 'test part B',​​​​​ filePath: 'test part B-1526297202118.CSV' },​​​​​
    { id: 1526297209980,​​​​​ text: 'Test Part C',​​​​​ filePath: 'Test Part C-1526297209966.CSV' }
]
```

But I only get:

```
[{ id: 1526297185466,​​​​​ text: 'test part a',​​​​​ filePath: 'test part a-1526297185451.CSV' }]
```

The whole object:

```
[{
"id": 1526297177970,
"text": "k",
"nodes": [
  {
    "id": 1526297185466,
    "tags": [1],
    "text": "test part a",
    "state": { "checked": true, "expanded": true },
    "filePath": "test part a-1526297185451.CSV"
  },
  {
    "id": 1526297195199,
    "tags": [1],
    "text": "New Product Set",
    "nodes": [
      {
        "id": 1526297202132,
        "tags": [1],
        "text": "test part B",
        "state": { "checked": true, "expanded": true },
        "filePath": "test part B-1526297202118.CSV"
      },
      {
        "id": 1526297209980,
        "tags": [1],
        "text": "Test Part C",
        "state": { "checked": true, "expanded": true },
        "filePath": "Test Part C-1526297209966.CSV"
      }
    ],
    "state": { "checked": true }
  }
],
"state": { "checked": true }
}]
```

Comment: A fiddle is fine, but please also post sample data here.

Comment: @ScottSauyet: I'll try to do that (SO said I had too much code when I tried earlier though!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call

```
 getKeysVals(thisObj[recurse], keys, recurse)
```

This will create a new `out` and return that, so you may add that to the current out:

```
out.push(...getKeysVals(thisObj[recurse], keys, recurse));
```

Comment: Awe man - that was it!? I've been stabbing at this code so long I missed that. I appreciate you spending your time on this - many thanks.

Comment: @JonasW. - thanks for point out the error in my "ready-fire-aim" answer :-)